# Memory exception in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Does the following code will increase the allocated memory continuously as it is called repeatedly?

```
  void ArrayStorage::merge(int low, int mid, int high)
    {
    int start = low;    
    int marker = low;
    int secondStart = mid + 1;

    temp = new string [high + 1];
        //rest of the code
    }
```

please share with me if you know about it...

Comment: I am obliged to mention [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  Are you aware of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, because you're not deleting the memory allocated by `new`.

The correct way is:

```
void ArrayStorage::merge(int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int start = low;    
    int marker = low;
    int secondStart = mid + 1;

    temp = new string [high + 1];
    //rest of the code
    delete[] temp; //free the memory 
}
```

In C++, there's no automatic memory management for dynamically allocated objects. Everytime you call `new` or `malloc`(this method is usually for C), you allocate memory in dynamic storage, which you are responsible for freeing, via `delete` or `free` respectively. In your case, you allocate an array of size `high + 1` which you need to free via `delete[]`.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, *maybe* `std::vector` is better suited, but it depends on what you want to do. Look it up.

Comment: Beware of exception safety, its better to use scoped/smart pointer

Comment: An even better way is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: assuming that you need fix sized array, use [array Class(TR1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983093.aspx) on `windows`.

Comment: @C-x C-t positive it will fit on the stack?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will, unless you are deleting the memory allocated everytime by

```
temp = new string [high + 1];
```

in your "rest of the code".

Answer (score 1):

When you call new you allocate memory off the heap.  This memory is freed in one of two ways;   the first way is someone calls delete on it (mainly you or a library you are using), and two is by terminating the program.

Just a pedantic note, it will eventually stop consuming memory, because your system will stop allowing new to work (there is an upper limit).